# What is the difference between a $k$-chain and a cycle?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

As a preface, my knowledge of math is limited to multivariable calculus and I do not have any formal education in algebraic topology. I am currently trying to grasp some basic ideas of the subject through video lectures on YouTube and using this book for some formal instruction: [Algebraic Topology — Allen Hatcher.](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html)

Currently I understand the mathematical definition of a chain as a formal sum of simplices, though I'm having difficulty understanding exactly what chain would also constitute a cycle.

My understanding of an algebraic cycle is that the term refers to any shape defined by an equation (conics, lines, etc) in $CP^2$ . On the other hand, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_(algebraic_topology)) Wikipedia article on chains states that any chain with zero *boundary* is an algebraic cycle. What does this mean? The book I'm using does not refer to anything of the sort.

Comment: These are two totally separate notions of "cycle".  (They are related, but the relationship is subtle and is not something you should try to understand yet.)  The second one is the one relevant to what you are trying to learn.

Comment: It's a definition.

Comment: Also Hatcher's book absolutely does refer to chains with zero boundary as cycles.  You may not have gotten to that part yet.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Thank you, I don't think I've reached that part yet. But it is the second definition which I am having difficulty understanding. By this logic would the surface of a Torus, for instance, be a cycle?

Comment: I suspect your example refers to a special case.  Though I don't know for sure.

Comment: Intuitively the surface of a torus appears to be a boundary, and so would be a cycle.  A cycle is a special type of $k$-chain, one whose boundary is zero.  Since the boundary of a boundary is zero, any boundary is a cycle.  This results in a special exact sequence known as a chain complex.  From this we get the _homology_.

Comment: @Chris Custer Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for - the explanation cleared all my difficulties in one line. Should I add this as an answer to my own question?

Comment: I guess you could.

Comment: @ChrisCuster The sequence you get is not exact, certainly not for the torus since there are nontrivial homology groups.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @NoelLundström.  It's been a long time, and memory didn't serve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris Custer put it in his comment,

> Intuitively the surface of a torus appears to be a boundary, and so would be a cycle. A cycle is a special type of $k$-chain, one whose boundary is zero. Since the boundary of a boundary is zero, any boundary is a cycle.